# Jackson serialisation fails by throwing KotlinReflectionInternalError when serializing model with empty list and minifyEnabled true

Tags: android, kotlin, jackson, proguard

I have `minifyEnabled true` in my `build.gradle` file and let's say I have a model

```kotlin
data class SomeModel(
    val numberList: List<Int>
)
```

It get's serialized properly when `numberList` variable have some value's

```kotlin
SomeModel(listOf(1, 2, 3))
```

but the serialization fails if the content of `numberList` is empty

```kotlin
SomeModel(listOf()) // or SomeModel(emptyList())
```

Above both cases work fine if I change code to `minifyEnabled false`

I serialize like this

```kotlin
jsonMapper.writeValueAsString(someModel)
```

My Jackson's `JsonMapper` looks like this

```kotlin
JsonMapper().apply {
    enable(MapperFeature.INFER_PROPERTY_MUTATORS)
    enable(MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_ENUMS)
    configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
    registerModule(KotlinModule())
}
```

I even have added the class in `proguard-rules.pro` file

```
-keep  class org.package.SomeModel {
    <fields>;
}

# tried this also
-keep  class org.package.SomeModel {
    *;
}
```

The error log are as follows

```
kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KotlinReflectionInternalError: No accessors or field is found for property val kotlin.collections.EmptyList.serialVersionUID: kotlin.Long
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KPropertyImplKt.computeCallerForAccessor(KPropertyImpl.kt:240)
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KPropertyImplKt.access$computeCallerForAccessor(KPropertyImpl.kt:1)
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KPropertyImpl$Getter$caller$2.invoke(KPropertyImpl.kt:156)
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KPropertyImpl$Getter$caller$2.invoke(KPropertyImpl.kt:147)
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.ReflectProperties$LazyVal.invoke(ReflectProperties.java:62)
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.ReflectProperties$Val.getValue(ReflectProperties.java:31)
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KPropertyImpl$Getter.getCaller(Unknown Source:7)
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.ReflectJvmMapping.getJavaMethod(ReflectJvmMapping.kt:63)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.KotlinAnnotationIntrospector.getCorrespondingGetter(KotlinAnnotationIntrospector.kt:145)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.KotlinAnnotationIntrospector.hasRequiredMarker(KotlinAnnotationIntrospector.kt:110)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.KotlinAnnotationIntrospector.access$hasRequiredMarker(KotlinAnnotationIntrospector.kt:23)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.KotlinAnnotationIntrospector$hasRequiredMarker$hasRequired$1.invoke(KotlinAnnotationIntrospector.kt:40)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.KotlinAnnotationIntrospector$hasRequiredMarker$hasRequired$1.invoke(KotlinAnnotationIntrospector.kt:23)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.ReflectionCache.javaMemberIsRequired(ReflectionCache.kt:56)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.KotlinAnnotationIntrospector.hasRequiredMarker(KotlinAnnotationIntrospector.kt:33)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotationIntrospectorPair.hasRequiredMarker(AnnotationIntrospectorPair.java:318)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotationIntrospectorPair.hasRequiredMarker(AnnotationIntrospectorPair.java:318)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.POJOPropertyBuilder.getMetadata(POJOPropertyBuilder.java:229)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.POJOPropertiesCollector._anyIndexed(POJOPropertiesCollector.java:1197)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.POJOPropertiesCollector._sortProperties(POJOPropertiesCollector.java:1099)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.POJOPropertiesCollector.collectAll(POJOPropertiesCollector.java:425)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.POJOPropertiesCollector.getJsonValueAccessor(POJOPropertiesCollector.java:227)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.BasicBeanDescription.findJsonValueAccessor(BasicBeanDescription.java:258)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BasicSerializerFactory.findSerializerByAnnotations(BasicSerializerFactory.java:391)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BasicSerializerFactory.buildCollectionSerializer(BasicSerializerFactory.java:705)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BasicSerializerFactory.buildContainerSerializer(BasicSerializerFactory.java:647)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializerFactory._createSerializer2(BeanSerializerFactory.java:200)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializerFactory.createSerializer(BeanSerializerFactory.java:169)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider._createUntypedSerializer(SerializerProvider.java:1473)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider._createAndCacheUntypedSerializer(SerializerProvider.java:1441)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.findPrimaryPropertySerializer(SerializerProvider.java:651)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.PropertySerializerMap.findAndAddPrimarySerializer(PropertySerializerMap.java:72)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter._findAndAddDynamic(BeanPropertyWriter.java:895)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:706)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:770)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:178)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider._serialize(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:480)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:319)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._writeValueAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4485)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(ObjectMapper.java:3740)
    at org.nvest.BiTool.test1(BiTool.kt:173)
    at org.bharti.axa.ui.HomeScreenActivity$onCreate$4.onClick(HomeScreenActivity.kt:92)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7509)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7486)
    at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:841)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28709)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:236)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8060)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:656)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:967)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error indicates that `No accessors or field is found for property val kotlin.collections.EmptyList.serialVersionUID: kotlin.Long`

So `kotlin.reflect` knows about `EmptyList.serialVersionUID` but it can't find it for Jackson to serialize the empty list. For it to know about `EmptyList.serialVersionUID` while it's not actually accessible likely means that it was in the `kotlin.Metadata` of `kotlin.collections.EmptyList` but not in the class itself.

Since this happens only with `minifyEnabled = true`, it appears that `r8` stripped `kotlin.collections.EmptyList.serialVersionUID` but didn't actually update the `kotlin.Metadata` of `kotlin.collections.EmptyList` to avoid incorrectly indicating that the field is still there.

This is likely a bug with `r8`, and `r8` is packaged with the android gradle plugin, so updating the android gradle plugin to the latest stable release should resolve the issue. If it doesn't, I recommend filing an r8 bug in the Google Issue Tracker.

Comment: Upgrading to latest version of android gradle plugin worked for me. Thanks a lot.